# How can I intercept the drag and drop inside an openoffice/libre office document in python/pyuno?

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, libreoffice, openoffice-writer, pyuno

I would like to intercept the drag and drop handling inside of a python/pyuno script inside of openoffice/libreoffice, how can this be done?